# What does it mean: "If you scream in Hilbert space, nobody will hear you!"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, hilbert-space

This question may not be appropriate for this site and if it so, sorry for that. Today, I have heard the following quote from one of my friends:

> If you scream in Hilbert space, nobody will hear you!

However, I don't get the idea. Can anybody explain what is meant by that?

Comment: I think it's a joke based on a quote from the Alien movie franchise

Comment: It seems that such soft-questions (v2) are better asked in e.g. the hbar chat room.

Comment: It's a joke, but not a good one: there's no obvious punning word play that suggests a punch-line justifying why it is harder to hear a scream in Hilbert space than some other kind of abstract mathematical space. 

A much better joke is: "what is yellow and has a complete norm? A banana space" (pun on Banach space)

Comment: "Why is there no construction worker in Hilbert space? --- Cause it's already complete"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it was a joke. I thought there was some physical knowledge behind it. Anyway, the jokes in the comments are enough for a funny evening. So I am happy for asking this.

Comment: badum tsh!  (snare drum)

Comment: Saunders Mac Lane liked to sing occasionally (on the original tune): "You can't get to the Heaven in the Banach space, 'coz God doesn't know of any such place" :D

Comment: When you scream, you emit sound waves of a certain power output, this energy flux is assumed so spread radially outward and be approximately conservative (have no divergence except at the source). By the divergence theorem, this implies an inverse power law intensity with the exponent being -(d-1) for d dimensions, thus, inverse square for 3D space, inverse cube for four dimensions,... and inverse infinite power for infinity dimensions. Thus, in Hilbert space, the sound intensity immediately falls to zero. I would have written this as an answer had the question not been closed.